# Changing a variable's value through another variable

Tags: objective-c, variables, pointers, variable-assignment

How can I substitute one variable `a` for another variable `b`, in order to change `b`?

For example:

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSString *b = @"b";
NSString *c = @"c";

a = b;
a = c;
```

In this case, the value of `b` is `@"b"`, right? I want to make the value of `b` `@"c"`, without using `b = c`. Probably I should try to understand pointers.

Please make sense of my poor explanation, and give me any advice you can.

Comment: The only piece of advice I can give you apart from writing `b = c;` is learning how to explain yourself in a meaningful manner. I cannot possibly make sense of this regardless of how strong I want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be confused because pointers are, frankly, kind of confusing at first. They are variables that hold memory locations. If you have two pointers that hold the same location, and you change the *contents* of that location using one pointer, then you can see those new contents via the other pointer. It still points to the same location, though.

```
int x = 10;

// xp is a pointer that has the address of x, whose contents are 10
int * xp = &x;
// yp is a pointer which holds the same address as xp
int * yp = xp;

// *yp, or "contents of the memory address yp holds", is 10
NSLog(@"%i", *yp);

// contents of the memory at x are now 62
x = 62;

// *yp, or "contents of the memory address yp holds", is now 62
NSLog(@"%i", *yp);
// But the address that yp holds has _not_ changed.
```

Based on your comment, yes, you can do this:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 62; 

// Put the address of x into a pointer
int * xp = &x;
// Change the value stored at that address
*xp = y;

// Value of x is 62
NSLog(@"%i", x);
```

And you can do the same thing with `NSString`s, although I can't think of a good reason for doing so. Change any `int` in the example to `NSString *`; the `int *` becomes `NSString **`. Change the assignments and the `NSLog()` format specifier as appropriate:

```
NSString * b = @"b";
NSString * c = @"c";

// Put the address of b into a pointer
NSString ** pb = &b;
// Change the value stored at that address
*pb = c;
// N.B. that this creates a memory leak unless the previous
// value at b is properly released.

// Value at b is @"c"
NSLog(@"%@", b);
```

Comment: Thank for answering again! Yes, that's exactly what i wanna do. but I can't declare like this "NSString **a;". so I'm gonna make next question to focus about this. Thanks!

Comment: I asked about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146733/how-to-declare-variable-of-nsstring-with-double-pointer let me know any advise when you have a time.